# Displaying two months on calendar at a time

Tags: gwt, datepicker, datebox

How can I display two months side by side in my calendar using `DateBox` or `DatePicker` in GWT?

Comment: There is no Calendar in GWT. Do you mean DatePicker?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Yeah, Exactly. It was a mistake. thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

You can set two DatePicker widgets side by side in a panel and synchronize their changes (i.e. when one is moved a month forward, the other moves a month forward too). I am afraid it would look very confusing to your users because each DatePicker is still going to have its own controls.

The only other option is to build this widget from scratch as a new Composite widget.

Comment: Maybe one possibility would be to have this two datepickers, but hidding one of them through styles.